# Why is my array being converted incorrectly to jsonp data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
var sv_defaultArray = new Array([]);

    sv_defaultArray[0] = "post 1";
    sv_defaultArray[1] = "post 2";
    sv_defaultArray[2] = "post 3";
```

Console states the array here is **["post 1", "post 2", "post 3"]**;

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(sv_defaultArray);
```

Console states the array here is **["post 1", "post 2", "post 3"]**;

```
  $.post("http://www.foobar.com/write.php", { 'array': myJsonString });
```

Array is posted as: **[\"post 1\",\"post 2\",\"post 3\"]**

What is going wrong, why is the data not getting converted to json and submitted as json too?

When i call the databack i am calling it as jsonp wrapped in a callback function

Comment: as far as I can see it this is a valid json string. if you want to have a {...} json string, you need an associative array.

Comment: i forgot to mention im actually calling the databack as jsonp wrapped in a function

Comment: This is the correct json format for Array, you can parse this with no issue. Not sure why you think it is 'wrong'. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: my php was adding magic quotes all fixed now thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to set `dataType` on `$.post`

```
$.post("http://www.foobar.com/write.php", 
    { 'array': myJsonString }, 
    function(){/* handle results here */},
    "json"
);
```

Anyway, you have plain Array, so it will be decoded the same way. If you need `{}` you have to encode associative array or object.

```
var data = {field1: 'data1', field2:'data2'};
//or
var data = new Array();
data['field1'] = 'data1';
data['field2'] = 'data2';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're double-encoding. Pass the actual array into `$.post`, not the JSON string.

```
$.post("http://www.foobar.com/write.php", { 'array': sv_defaultArray });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing is casting your JSON object into string then POSTing the string representation of the JSON object to the server. That's why the double quotes are escaped; double quotes inside a string needed to be escaped as described in the JSON specification.

So when you do `{'array':myJsonString}` You actually get the following JSON representation:

```
{'array': "['POST1', 'post2', 'post3']"}
```

Note that `'array'` is actually type of string.

If you want your data to be POSTed as JSON array, simply do this:

```
{'array':sv_defaultArray}
```